# Converting raw unicode to text

Tags: python, selenium

I am coding with python 3.8 to get some text from html sources with selenium.

I got something like this from `page_source` (the `html_source` is too long, so I just show the focus part for output of `print()`):

```
html_source = browser.page_source
print(html_source)
>>> \u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4
```

But my expected output is:

```
print(html_source)
>>> 免費資源網路社群
```

I tried to do this:

```
html_source.encode(‘utf-8’)
# but the result is same
print(html_source)
>>> \u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4
```

Seems it is because the Unicode in `html_source` is raw string. So how can I convert the raw Unicode to my expected output?

I am new to coding, and get mess about text encode decode. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Supplement:

```
# I discover that r’’ string will give a similar result as above
html_source = r”\u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4”
print(html_source)
>>> \u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4

# while if the string is normal
html_source = “\u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4”
print(html_source)
>>> 免費資源網絡社群
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python 3:**

```
s = r'\u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4'
print(s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

**Python 2**

```
s = r'\u514d\u8cbb\u8cc7\u6e90\u7db2\u8def\u793e\u7fa4'
print (s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
utf8string = unicodestring.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: I tried it, when I run `print(utf8string)` it gives: `>>> b’\\u514d\\u8cbb\\u8cc7\\u6e90\\u7db2\\u8def\\u793e\\u7fa4’ `
and the type is ‘bytes’